# How can I clear form.isDirty programmatically?

Tags: vuejs3

If there is away in vue 3.2.30 app to clear isDirty for form manually?
With form defined I show if some field is modified :

```
let formEditor = ref(useForm({
    id: is_insert.value ? '' : props.currency.id,
    name: is_insert.value ? 'name ' + new Date() : props.currency.name,
    ...
    active: is_insert.value ? false : (props.currency.active === 1 ? true : false),
    ordering: is_insert.value ? '9' + (new Date().getSeconds()) : props.currency.ordering,
    updated_at: is_insert.value ? '' : props.currency.updated_at,
}))

     ...
            <div v-show="formEditor.isDirty">
                You have unsaved data
            </div>
     ...

            axios.post(route('admin.currencies.activate', formEditor.value.id))
                .then(({data}) => {
                    formEditor.value.active = data.currency.active
                    formEditor.value.updated_at = data.currency.updated_at
                    Swal.fire(
                        'CURRENCY STATUS!',
                        'Currency was successfully activated !',
                        'success'
                    )
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.error(e)
                })
```

But in Axios request above I modify some fields on succcess request
And I need to clear formEditor.isDirty programmatically...

Thanks!